# Simple form not working anymore, since adding jquery tablesorter on same page

Tags: jquery, submit, tablesorter

I'm using jquery and tablesorter plugin to sort a table in a php-page, which works flawless.

Further I have this form in it:

```
<form name="newrs" id="newrs" action="edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" onSubmit="">

<input class="btn" id="bbtnNew" name="button" type="submit" value="New Recordset" />
</form>
```

But since I added the jquery/tablesorter functionality, the form doesn't work anymore. (If I click on submit, nothing happens.

- What causes this behaviour?
- And how can I overcome this?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

....
Initializing the tablesorter with this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( { sortList: [ [4,1] ] , widgets: ['zebra'] } ); 
    } 
    ); 
     </script>
```

Comment: Could we see the jQuery you're using to initialize the tablesorter?

Comment: OK Sorry, as it seems, there was some other (non-jquery) Javascript code which caused that behaviour.

SOLVED.

Answer (score 1):

OK Sorry, as it seems, there was some other (non-jquery) Javascript code which caused that behaviour. SOLVED

Comment: Can you give some details of the non-jquery script that you removed to get the form working. Did the script refer to #myTable or some other tablesorter element? I've a simular issue but i only include the three scripts - jquery, tablesorter and a tableserver init function.